# Can I push this rails calculation into the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, active-record-query

I'm trying to increase my app's efficiency by doing work in the database rather than in the app layer, and I'm wondering if I can move this calculation into the database.

Models:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
  has_many :items, :through => :lines
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :item
  # also has a 'quantity' attribute (integer)
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
  has_many :offers, :through => :lines
  # also has a 'price' attribute (decimal)
end
```

What I want to do is calculate the price of an offer. Currently I have a price method in the Offer class:

```
def price
  self.lines.inject(0) do |total, line|
    total + line.quantity * line.item.price
  end
end
```

I suspect it may be possible to do a `Offer.sum` calculation instead that would get the answer directly from the DB rather than looping through the records, but the [Calculations section of the ActiveRecord query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations) doesn't have enough detail to help me out. Anybody?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that you can do this with [`sum`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000296). Something like this:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def price
    self.lines.sum 'lines.quantity * items.price', :joins => :item
  end
end
```

When you call e.g. `Offer.find( some_id ).price` the above will construct a query something like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM( lines.quantity * items.price ) AS total
  FROM lines
  INNER JOIN items ON items.id = lines.item_id
  WHERE lines.offer_id = <some_id>
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you're better off with SQL.

```sql
SELECT SUM( lines.quantity * items.price ) AS total
  FROM offers
  INNER JOIN lines ON offers.id = lines.offer_id
  INNER JOIN items ON items.id = lines.item_id
  WHERE offers.id = 1
;
```